# Обмен через указатели

Tags: c, указатели

Можно ли как то реализовать функцию swap которая не будет привязана к определенному типу?

Comment: для свапа нужно знать размер типа. Без него будет всё странно. На С++ можно. Если размер типа фиксирован тоже. Через свой врапер - легко.

Comment: Функцию - нельзя. Можно - макрос.

Comment: А подробнее можно?

Comment: Можно, функция должна принимать тип void** для обоих параметров, естественно параметры должны быть ссылками на объект. Но следить за соответствием типов данных вам придётся самостоятельно.

Comment: @NewView: Почему именно `void **`? А чем плох просто `void *`?

Comment: Просто ссылка будет изменена только внутри функции свап, пример: `swap(void **a, void **b) { void **c = a; *a = *b; *b = *c; }` так будет изменён передаваемый указатель. Соответственно: `char *a = "qwerty", *b = " poiuytre"; swap(&a,&b); `

Comment: @NewView: Во-первых, так нельзя `&a` - это `char **`, а не `void **`, т.е. типы несовместимы. Во-вторых, автор хотел функцию для обмена "чего угодно", а не только указателей. В-третьих, чего вы хотите добиться через `void **c = a` - не ясно вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сделал я:

```
void swap_s(char *a, char *b, size_t n)
{
    char tmp;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Вроде тут ничего хитрого:

```
void Swap(void * const p_left, void * const p_right, size_t const bytes_count)
{
    size_t byte_index;
    for(byte_index = 0; bytes_count != byte_index; ++byte_index)
    {
        uint8_t * const p_left_byte = ((uint8_t *) p_left) + byte_index;
        uint8_t * const p_right_byte = ((uint8_t *) p_right) + byte_index;
        uint8_t const tmp = *p_left_byte;
        *p_left_byte = *p_right_byte;
        *p_right_byte = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не в обиду, соберите, превратите в ассемблер и посмотрите количество процессорных тиков с такой реализацией, будете шокированы, как минимум..:)

Comment: ага, конечно - https://godbolt.org/g/CPhfq1 - компиляторы сейчас достаточно умные и делают очень красивый код.

Comment: Спасибо, незнал об этом сайте, наглядно.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ну в c99 можно еще проще!
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    char temp[size]; // std=c99
    memcpy(temp, b,    size);
    memcpy(b,    a,    size);
    memcpy(a,    temp, size);
}
```

Comment: Памяти в стеке многовато скушает (вроде бы)

Comment: size надо знать, и копирование это лишние телодвижения при быстром свапе, можно использовать atomic built in функции (разный синтаксис у разных компиляторов, есть уневерсальные врапперы)

Comment: Вам ОС не даст такое сделать на практике.

Answer (score 0):

вот собственно [рабочий](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eef62f8b1ebdc942) пример. В комментариях я допустил ошибку, жаль не поправить, `void *c` это одинарная ссылка.
приведу тут правильный код функции swap:

```
#define __swap_wrapper(A,B) __swap((void**)&A, (void**)&B)

void __swap(void **a, void **b) {
    void *c = *a;
    *a = *b; *b = c;
}
```

__swap_wrapper - враппер для удобства описания, чтоб код не захламлять.
можно также использовать intrinsics ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html)) с memory barrier, итд

### Измененный вариант

Измененный вариант, с макросами определения типа и копированием данных,
макросы базовых типов, все приводить не стал, можно добавлять по собственному вкусу, заточено под сборку gcc.

---

Макрос и функции:

```
#define __swap_wrapper(A,B) __extension__ \
    (__builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), int[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const int[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), unsigned int[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const unsigned int[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), short[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const short[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), unsigned short[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const unsigned short[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), unsigned long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const unsigned long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), long long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const long long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), unsigned long long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), unsigned const long long[]), __swap(A, B, sizeof(A), sizeof(B)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), char*), __swap_p((void**)&A, (void**)&B), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const char*), __swap_p((void**)&A, (void**)&B), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), char[]), __swap(A, B, (sizeof(A) - 1), (sizeof(B) - 1)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const char[]), __swap(A, B, (sizeof(A) - 1), (sizeof(B) - 1)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), unsigned char*), __swap_p((void**)&A, (void**)&B), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const unsigned char*), __swap_p((void**)&A, (void**)&B), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), unsigned char[]), __swap(A, B, (sizeof(A) - 1), (sizeof(B) - 1)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const unsigned char[]), __swap(A, B, (sizeof(A) - 1), (sizeof(B) - 1)), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), void*), __swap_p((void**)&A, (void**)&B), \
            __builtin_choose_expr( \
        __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(A), const void*), __swap_p((void**)&A, (void**)&B), \
    __swap(A, B, sizeof(*A), sizeof(*B)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))


void __swap_p(void **a, void **b) {
    void *c = *a;
    *a = *b; *b = c;
}

void __swap(void *a, void *b, size_t na, size_t nb)
{
    if ((!na) || (na != nb)) { return; }

    char *va = (char*)a,
         *vb = (char*)b;

    if (va == vb) { return; }

    __builtin_prefetch(va + na, 1, 1);
    __builtin_prefetch(vb + nb, 1, 1);

    while (na--)
    {
        va[na] ^= vb[na];
        vb[na] ^= va[na];
        va[na] ^= vb[na];
    }
}
```

ну и собственно [рабочий](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be12a57be0162860) пример (*изменен*).

P.S. на досуге глянул и объединил обе функции, так же расширил типы на массивы.
Как мне кажется,вполне юзабельно.

Comment: Эта функция нормально работает, если ее применять к переменным размером с указатель. Если меньше - свапается смежная память, если больше - последние байты не свапаются.

Comment: Это функция обмен местами указателей `void *`. Все остальное она может менять местами лишь "на везении". Более того, попытка менять местами что-либо другое будет грубым нарушением правил strict aliasing, то есть работать это в общем случае не будет.

Comment: Конечно, это обмен местами указателей void *, собственно что от неё и требуется, по сути. 'что либо другое' не меняется, меняются местами именно указатели. Вопрос то был можно или нет свапить указатели независимо от типа, ответ можно. Далее надо смотреть где и с какими данными её преминять, естественно этот подход подойдёт не везде и фактически он не изменяет источники, меняются только указатели, что правильно, и правил strict aliasing оно именно по этому и не нарушает.

Comment: Если бы автор привёл пример кода, где отражен тип данных и ситуацию в которой необходим свап данных, тогда можно было бы рассматривать предметное решение, пока это прикладная теория :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, мне кажеться что благодаря кастингу в __swap_wrapper данные выравниваются, или я ошибаюсь? То есть если источник меньше указателя, смежная память затронута не будет.

Comment: *"Вопрос то был можно или нет свапить указатели независимо от типа"* Ну, вроде в вопросе про указатели ни слова. *"данные выравниваются"* Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Что свапим, родилось по ходу обсуждения :) вообще свапить все что угодно не глядя не выйдет, надо более точный вопрос. Или хотя бы список возможных типов подлежащих свопу.

Comment: Нет, ну макросами можно что угодно свапнуть. Что-нибудь вроде `#define swap_wrapper(x,y) swap(&x, &y, sizeof(x))`, где `swap()` - функция из ответа Антона.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Да, да, да, макросами можно, но типы бы неплохо знать, sizeof со ссылками не даст нужной глубины копирования.

Comment: Например в С++ `std::swap()` по указателям не переходит, так что имхо все нормально.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, соглашусь, это так. Для C поделился бы наработками, как макросами определять тип и соответственно размер, но необходимы возможные типы данных. Будет время, накидаю пример, сам использую такой подход для удобства. Чтобы функция принимала любые входные параметры из перечисленного списка типов.

Comment: @NewView: Такая функция позволяет свапить только указатели `void *` и совместимые с ними по объектному представлению указатели, т.е. например `char *`. Свапить указатели `int *` такой функцией формально нельзя.

Comment: @Ant, гляньте рабочий пример, вроде можно и int* и double* и float* :) итд. А если нельзя, то из каких соображений? при побайтном то копировании?

Comment: @NewView: Я имел в виду именно первую функцию, которая копирует не побайтно, а как два  `void *` указателя.

Comment: При приведении примера первой функции я руководствовался названием темы обсуждения 'Обмен через указатели' :)